# Open file for editing in new window inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I need to open a file with text editor in Eclipse. I need to do this in a piece of code. I have the file name and the file path stored in different variables. How can I do this ?
Thank you !

Comment: I cannot understand what's the problem here. `I have the name of the file and its path stored in a variable`! So you cannot check the variable? You need something else? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I edited the question in an understandable manner !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// Get the current page

IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

// Get IFile

IPath path = new Path("workspace relative path");
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);

// Open default editor for the file

IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
```

If you have a file which is not in the current workspace you can use:

```
File file = new File("path to file");

IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore(file.toURI());

IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
```

Some editors may not like files that are not in the workspace.

To open a specific editor you can use:

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file, "editor id");
```

For example `org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor` for the basic text editor.

Comment: What is the library for IDE ? My Eclipse doesn't recognize it

Comment: `IDE` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin

Comment: Workspace relative path like this :  ./project package/folder/file ?

Comment: Right click on the file in Package or Project Explorer and select Properties. In the Resource tab the 'Path' value shows you the workspace relative path.

Comment: the path is in the following manner :  /project_package_name/folder_where_the_file_is/file_name   but I still have that error....

Comment: The file must be in the workspace that you are testing with, that is not the same as your development workspace. If you want to open a file that is not in the test workspace try the 'openEditorOnFileStore' method.

Comment: You mean in the second window when I run the plugin, no ?

Comment: Yes, when you do Run > Eclipse Application a completely new Eclipse is launched using a new workspace.

Comment: This means that I have to import my project there once again ?

Comment: If you want to use the `IFile` style yes you have to put anything you want to work with in the test workspace.

Comment: I  have solved the problem, my file opens in system editor not in eclipse text editor....